# Validating emails using checkdnsrr, a good or bad solution?

Tags: php, regex, http, email-validation

I am using the below code to validate emails

```
if (checkdnsrr($domain , "MX")) {
    echo 'mx - pass <br>';
} else {
    echo 'mx - fail <br>';
}
```

My desire is to check that the domain is valid and has an MX record.

I am already using a regular expression to check the email format, but people enter things like someone@gmail.con which obviously is wrong but pases basic format validation.

I want to validate further but I do not want to go too far and get false negatives.

Does anyone see any issue with my solution or have a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your solution is perfectly fine! However, before you even make a DNS call, I'd recommend that you first validate the email address with FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL and then pass it for MX DNS check.

While, it may not be needed to check if the MX record exists, but you're looking to avoid bounce emails, go ahead!

Comment: @MartinSmith Perfect!

Comment: Use `FILTER_SANTIZE_EMAIL` first. Then use `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`.

Comment: Just to add a note of caution about ```FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL``` – it can convert a mis-typed invalid email address into a valid but incorrect email address. For example, if jeff9@example.com pressed the shift key too early and therefore typed jeff(@example.com by mistake. ```FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL``` would then remove the open-parenthesis and send jeff9's email to jeff@example.com instead. I'd rather catch the invalid email address, display an error and let the user handle it, than let ```FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL``` try to "fix" it for me!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, using `checkdnsrr()` is a good idea. When to use it is what you should focus on. I use a four pass system. Here is the skeleton, not the exact organization of what I do for email.

### Four Pass System

**Pass 1**) My custom filter using `filter_input_array()` and this rule (where filter occurs in a method of a class/object. Add elements as needed (for other fields).

```
$customFilterRules = [
    'email' => ['filter'  => FILTER_CALLBACK,
                'flags'   => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
                'options' => [$this, 'scrubber']
];
```

---

**Pass 2**) Use `filter_input_array()` with this filter rule. Add more elements as needed (for other fields).

```
$phpFilterRules = [
    'email' => ['filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL,
                'flags'  => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR]
];
```

---

**Pass 3)** Use `filter_var_array()` on the output of `filter_input_array()` with this validation rule. Add more rules as necessary.

```
$phpValidationRules = [
    'email' => ['filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL,
                'flags'  => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR]
];
```

---

**Pass 4**) Check the following with an `EmailValidator` class. Also, if you don't like using `filter_input_array()`, here are some methods from this class that might be helpful, generally. Alter as necessary.

Oh, I also check the basic, application specific, acceptable length of an email address with:

```
$length = mb_strlen($email, 'UTF-8') //Make a decision based on this.
```

Additionally, I have a great, application specific, e-mail regular expression I use with `preg_match()`. I only accept 128 characters in e-mail addresses.

```
'/(?>\A[A-Za-z0-9_-][A-Za-z0-9_.-]{0,62}?[A-Za-z0-9_-]{0,1}@{1}?(?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{1}?){1}?(?:[A-Za-z0-9.-]{0,61}?[A-Za-z0-9]{1}?){0,1}?){1,127}?\.{1}?[a-z]{2,20}?\z){1}?/u'
```

---

### Here are some `EmailValidator` methods.

```
/**
 * Compares 2 email addresses. If 1, just keep going.
 */
private function sameEmailAddress()
{
    if (count($this->filteredInputArray) === 2) {  //If there are two.
        if ($this->identical($this->filteredInputArray['email1'], $this->filteredInputArray['email2'])) {
            return true;
        }

        $this->testResultsArray['email1'] = false;
        $this->testResultsArray['email2'] = false;
        $this->errorMessagesArray['email1'] = 'Does not match e-mail below.';
        $this->errorMessagesArray['email2'] = 'Does not match e-mail above.';
        return false;
    }

    if (count($this->filteredInputArray) === 1) {  //If there is only 1.
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Finds problems with e-mail as a whole.
 * There is a regular expression you can do this with.
 */
private function consecutivePeriodTest ($emailAddress, &$errorMessage)
{
    if (!preg_match('/\A(?!..)+?\z/', $emailAddress)) {
        return true;
    }

    $errorMessage = 'Consecutive periods are illegal!';
    return false;
}
```

### **Finally**, I use `checkdnsrr()`.

```
/**
 * Given an array of unique domains, check DNS MX records.
 */
private function mxDNSPing(array $uniqueDomains)
{   
    $badDomains = [];

    foreach ($uniqueDomains as $key => $domain) {
        if (!checkdnsrr($domain, 'MX')) {
            $this->testResultsArray[$key] = false;
            $this->errorMessagesArray[$key] = 'No DNS MX records found.';
            $badDomains[$key] = $domain;
        }
    }

    return $badDomains;
}
```

### Determining what is wrong with the email address.

```
/**
 * Finds problems with local or domain parts.
 * Should break up into two methods, though.
 */
private function emailPartProblemFinder($string, &$errorMessage)
{
    $emailParts = $this->string->getEmailAddressParts($string); //explode() on `@`

    if (count($emailParts) !== 2) {
        $errorMessage = 'Invalid e-mail address!';
    } else {
        list($localPart, $domain) = $emailParts;

        $localLength  = mb_strlen($localPart);
        $domainLength = mb_strlen($domain);

        if ($localLength === 0) {
            $errorMessage = 'Missing local part of address.';
        } elseif ($localLength > 64) {
            $errorMessage = 'Only 64 characters are alloed before the @ symbol ('.$localLength.' given)';
        } elseif (mb_strrpos($string, '.') === ($localLength - 1)) {
            $errorMessage = 'The local part of an email address cannot end with a period (.).';
        } elseif (mb_strpos($string, '..') >= 0) {
            $errorMessage = 'The local part of an email address cannot contain consecutive periods (..).';
        } elseif ($domainLength < 4) { //x.yy, is my minimum domain format.
            $errorMessage = 'Domain part < 4 characters. ('.$domainLength.' given)';
        } elseif ($domainLength > 253) {
            $errorMessage = 'Domain part exceeds 253 characters. ('.$domainLength.' given)';
        }
    }

    return;
}

/**
 * Finds problems with e-mail as a whole.
 */
private function emailAddressProblemFinder($string, $max, &$errorMessage)
{
    $length = mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8');
    $atSymbolCount = mb_substr_count($string, '@', 'UTF-8');

    if ($length === 0) {
        return false;    //The reason was already assigned to the error message inside of $this->validateInput()
    } elseif ($length > $max) {
        $errorMessage = 'Exceeds max length (' . $max . ' characters)';
    } elseif ((mb_strpos($string, '@') === 0)) {
        $errorMessage = 'Cannot start with a @';
    } elseif ((mb_strrpos($string, '@') === ($length - 1))) {
        $errorMessage = 'Cannot end with a @';
    } elseif ($atSymbolCount > 1) {
        $errorMessage = '@ appears '.$atSymbolCount.' times.';
    } elseif ((mb_strpos($string, '@') === false)) {
        $errorMessage = 'The @ symbol is missing.';
    } elseif (mb_strpos($string, '.') === 0) {
        $errorMessage = 'The local part of an email address cannot start with a period (.).';
    } else {
        $this->emailPartProblemFinder($string, $errorMessage);
    }

    return;
}
```

The method, `emailAddressProblemFinder()` is only called to discover what went wrong. It calls `emailPartProblemFinder()`, if necessary.

My point is that there are tons of tests you could do before using `checkdnsrr()`. The wisdom of this is something for you and others to debate. Anyway, I always like to see what other people do!

Comment: You da real MVP here! ;)

Comment: @Romanulus Thank you. If I helped, I am glad. I condensed the code to be PSR-2 compliant.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `chkdnsrr()` for years without a problem until this week (with pre-checking as described above), when it kicked out a valid domain (`dfp.com.my`) for no apparent reason. I can't find out what caused this, so I have now ensured that nslookup is installed (on CentOS, that's `sudo yum install bind-utils`), and used the following:

```
function isDomainValid($domain) {
    $output = [];
    $return = false;
    exec("nslookup $domain", $output, $return);
    return $return === 0;
}
```

Comment: This has some promise but has horrible implementation. If you're reading this and thinking about using the code above PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE sanitize and strip the $domain variable before ever thinking about passing it into an exec function. It's not always possible but you should NEVER let a user defined value touch an exec or shell_exec function. -- A better solution would be to notify the php.net team about the error in question.

Comment: @CodeJunkie: I do masses of sanitising, but it's very similar to Anthony Rutledge's post above, so that didn't seem worth repeating. I could post the code if really wanted. On reading your post, I checked to see if dfp.com.my still fails, and it doesn't any more, so either PHP have fixed the bug or the domain owner has made some changes - I can't tell which, so there's no point in reporting it now.